# How to avoid memory error when using recursion? (Fibonacci Numbers)

Tags: python, recursion, memory-efficient

I have the following exercise:

```
'''FIBONACCI

   Compute the n'th Fibonacci number fib(n), defined recursively:

      fib(0) == 0, fib(1) == 1, fib(n) = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

   Input:

      A single line containing an integer n, 0 <= n <= 10.000

   Output:

      A single line with the integer fib(n).

   Example:

     Input:   10

     Output:  55
'''
```

My raw attempt so to speak:

```
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    if n >= 2:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    
n = int(input())  # Read integer n from standard input
print(fib(n))
```

However this code can only handle up to around n = 500 before reaching maximum recursion depth. To increase that number and create code that can handle up to 10 000, I have tried two things: 1) To increase maximum recursion depth and 2) To use memoization in the form of a decorator. Now the code can handle up to about n = 2000:

```
import sys
from functools import lru_cache

sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    if n >= 2:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

n = int(input())  # Read integer n from standard input
print(fib(n))
```

With n > 2000 I get an memory error (stack overflow). How do I fix this? What more can I do? Is it even possible with my recursive function or do I have to change it in some way to make it work? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just because it is *defined* recursively, does not mean that you need to *implement* it with recursion.

Comment: A valid point and I have thought about this. I tested for large n how Binet's Formula would handle it but I got a numbers too large error there. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Binet's_formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple implementation of the `n`th Fibonacci number.  There is no need to use recursion.

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        fa, fb = 0, 1
        for i in range(2, n + 1):
            fa, fb = fb, fa + fb
        return fb
```

(Note: this is not the fastest. It is O(*n*). An O(log *n*) solution is available -- e.g. [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/), see their method 5.)

Comment: Beautiful, that works! I guess you could make it slightly shorter by writing "if n < 2: return n". But thank you very much :)

Comment: @Jacobiman Sure, one could tweak it. Maybe there is even some more fancy optimisation / clever formula that could be used instead. The main point is simply that recursion is unnecessary. In fact the recursive example shown is particularly problematic, as you will discover if you put a `print(n)` statement into your routine and discover how many times it is being called for numbers smaller than your original `n` - hopefully you can see why.

Answer (score 0):

With a recursive implementation, you will almost end up with trouble when trying to go to such great depths. Like @alaniwi stated, you can always implement it in a non-recursive method. Here's a `O(n)` time solution with a `O(1)` space complexity. (Note: Theoretically you can even get a `O(log n)` solution.)

```py
from collections import deque

def fib(n):
    past = deque([1], maxlen=2)
    for _ in range(n): past.appendleft(sum(past))
    return past[0]
```

Because the fibonacci function only requires the last two values of f, we can store only those and bubble upwards.

Answer (score 0):

In the task they give a recursive definition of the fibonacci sequence but nothing is said about a recursive implementation.
This is an iterative implementation of the recursive definition:

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    f1, f2 = 0, 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        f1, f2 = f2, f1 + f2
    return f2
```